# PHP function strange array return

Tags: php

I have this function:

```
function Test ($test)
{
        [...]

        if ( $res->num_rows == 0 )
                return "BAD";

        $magic_array = array();

        while ( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() )
                $magic_array[] = $row["hex_stream"];

        return $magic_array;
}
```

if I try:

```
    $result_array = Test($test);

    var_dump($result_array);
```

It prints:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "FFD8FFE1"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "FFD8FFE0"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "FFD8FFE8"
}
string(3) "BAD"
```

It seems like Test() is returning $magic_array and "BAD" at the same time.

Why is it happening?

Thank you

Comment: Is your var_dump() in a loop and perhaps called twice?

Comment: Not possible. `return` immediately terminates the function it's being executed in. there's NO way you could "return" from a function yet keep executing more code within that function. You are probably calling Test twice, where the second call has a 0-row result.

Comment: I'm calling only once the function, after var_dump() i've put an exit(1) so that is not the problem.

Comment: how are you calling the test()

Comment: $result_array = Test($test);

Answer (score -2):

your test() is being called twice

1st time you get your results from var_dump

2nd time in you get bad because

```
if ( $res->num_rows == 0 ) {
    return "BAD";
}
```

Its good practice to use {} in your if and while statements

Comment: why would you down vote this. its obviously being called twice since you have a return in it......Think about it

Comment: the fact that you prefer curly brackets doesn't mean that it is wrong to use none, and it certainly won't have lead to this error

Comment: i was just mentioning it being good practice and never once mentioned it being the reason it not working. if you read my response fully you will see i said its being called twice

Comment: If i put var_dump() inside Test() function before last return it shows ok, but outside the function it seems to be concatenated array + "BAD"

Comment: I'm sorry, I read "2nd time in you get bad because its good practice to use {} in your if and while statements"